# Define Function using another Function and plot

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

I have a function defined by

`f[x_, y_] := 1/(x^2+1) + 1/(y^2+1);`

I can plot this function perfectly.

Then I want to `StreamPlot` the gradient of that function so I do:

`myGrad[x_, y_] = Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}]]`

(I also tried some different approaches with `:=` and `Evaluate` and `Function` here.)

Sadly

`StreamPlot[myGrad[x, y], {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2, 5}]`

produces a blank plot. On the other hand, using the output as `%xyz` from the `myGrad` definition as the 1st argument in the `StreamPlot` call, renders a plot.

So, how do I reuse a functions result as definition of a new function and use the new function in a plot?

Comment: On my machine "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" your code produces a plot, no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f, myGrad]
f[x_, y_] := 1/(x^2 + 1) + 1/(y^2 + 1);
myGrad[x_, y_] := Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}];
```

Use the option `Evaluated -> True` or wrap the first argument with `Evaluate` in `StreamPlot`:

```
StreamPlot[myGrad[x, y], {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2, 5}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

```
StreamPlot[Evaluate @ myGrad[x, y], {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2, 5}]
```

> same picture

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick!